# sobre modificar el <meta name="description" content="/> y <meta name="keywords" content="/> cuando los llaman por php

Tags: php

Acabo de retomar un proyecto que yo no inicie, y hay que modificar:

```
<meta name="description" content="/>
<meta name="keywords" content="/>
```

pero son llamados por `PHP` en el siguiente código:

```
<?php
    if ($head['description']) {
        echo '<meta name="description" content="'.htmlspecialchars($head['description']).'" />'."\n";
    }
    if ($head['metaTags']['name']['keywords']) {
        echo '<meta name="keywords" content="'.htmlspecialchars($head['metaTags']['name']['keywords']).'" />'."\n";
    }       

    echo '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="'.htmlspecialchars($head['metaTags']['http-equiv']['content-type']).'; charset='.$this->getCharset().'" />'."\n";
    ?>
```

Alguien podría indicarme donde están los archivos que son llamados o si es desde otro tipo de archivo o comando.

Gracias, gente
Saludos..

Comment: Ese archivo es una extension de otro. La variable $headr[] contiene el valor que buscar. Hay que buscar donde esta declarada la variable $head[] y tendras el control de lo que quieres.

Comment: muchas gracias, lo voy a checar